# Spring JDBC Template batchUpdate to update thousands of records in a tbale

Tags: java, oracle, sql-update, spring-jdbc, batch-updates

I have an update query which I am trying to execute through batchUpdate method of spring jdbc template. This update query can potentially match 1000s of rows in EVENT_DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE table which needs to be get updated. Will updating thousands of rows in a table cause any issue in production database apart from timeout? like, will it crash database or slowdown the performance of entire database engine for other connections...etc?

Is there a better way to achieve this instead of firing single update query in spring JDBC template or JPA? I have the following settings for jdbc template.

```
this.jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
jdbc.setFetchSize(1000);
jdbc.setQueryTimeout(0); // zero means there is no limit
```

The update query:

```
UPDATE EVENT_DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE eda
   SET eda.ATTRIBUTE_VALUE = 'claim',
       eda.LAST_UPDATED_DATE = SYSDATE,
       eda.LAST_UPDATED_BY = 'superUsers'
 WHERE     eda.DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_ID = 4002
       AND eda.EVENT_ID IN
              (WITH category_data
                       AS (    SELECT c.CATEGORY_ID
                                 FROM CATEGORY c
                           START WITH CATEGORY_ID = 495984
                           CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = PRIOR CATEGORY_ID)
               SELECT event_id
                 FROM event e
                WHERE EXISTS
                         (SELECT 't'
                            FROM category_data cd
                           WHERE cd.CATEGORY_ID = e.PRIMARY_CATEGORY_ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is one time thing, I normally first select the records which needs to be updated and put in a temporary table or in a csv, and I make sure that I save primary key of those records in a table or in a csv. Then I read records in batches from temporary table or csv, and do the update in the table using the primary key. This way tables are not locked for a long time and you can have fixed set of records added in the batch which needs update and updates are done using primary key so it will be very fast. And if any update fails then you know which records got failed by logging out the failed records primary key in a log file or in an error table. I have followed this approach many time for updating millions of records in the PROD database, as it is very safe approach.

Comment: No, it is not one time thing, we are planning to provide it as feature available through MBean in a JMX console where super user will perform this activity occasionally and needs to be done in PROD without causing any issue or delay in the original table and the updates are span across multiple tables

Comment: But your above update query is happening in one table. Even if you want to do it occassionaly, then also same concept should apply, first retrieve data from the impacted tables as retrieve normally do no put lock on the tables. Once data is retrieved then update the impacted tables using its primary key(s).

Comment: I have just provided only one sample query above, I have bunch of such queries and being sent it as part of batchUpdate, creating temporary tables in PROD is not allowed. I also have some transaction timeout issue as well during this batchUpdate due to the fact that each of these update queries can potentially update 100s of 1000s of records

Comment: Yes update is giving transaction time out and its not mandatory tohave an additional PROD temp table, instead you can keep the fetched records in your memory. Main point here is, first do select which should not lock any records on the table then keep those fetched records in the memory, then in batches of 1000 run the update query using primary key.  Also if your select query is timing out then you need to improve the query performance by modifying the query or adding indexed in your tables.

Comment: I am almost following this approach, but fetching 10,000 records every time and calling batchUpdate by sending all the cumulative update queries to database (which means for 100, 000 records to get updated I constructed 10 update queries and sending it to database), the entire batch process is getting transaction timeout (unexpected error: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionTimedOutException: Transaction timed out: deadline was), is there way to set custom transaction timeout before calling batchUpdate of JdbTemplate?